# Space block relative to above content

Tags: html, css

I have the following snippet in which there are 2 divs, one after the other. On `.circle` I have a hover effect in which a border expands around the image. The second div then 'flows' under this one and will hold additional content.

I only want the hover effect to appear around the `img`. To achieve this, I set `p{position: absolute;}` so the border **does not** encompass the `p` tag.

**The problem is, how do I keep a consistant margin between the 2 divs?**

**Note:**

- I don't know the number of lines of text there will be under the `img` so hard coding `.circle{margin-top: ?px}` is not an option.
- I want the hover effect to still trigger when I hover the `p` tag.

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle > p {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle>img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: #54314E solid 4px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle:hover:before,
.circle:focus:before,
.circle:active:before,
.circle.active:before {
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -15px;
}

#underDiv {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <p>OUR SERVICE PROMISE</p>
</div>

<div id="underDiv"><div>
```

Comment: this what you're going for? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpXyOP

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes that works perfectly, thank you. Please create an answer for me to accept.

Comment: You're welcome. Wasn't sure if that's what you were going for. I'll submit as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the circle in a new element, and draw the ring around the circle using the new element, then trigger the ring to expand when you hover over the parent that wraps both the circle and the paragraph.

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle > p {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
.circle>div {
  position: relative;
}

.circle>div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: #54314E solid 4px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle>div>img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.circle:hover > div:before {
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -15px;
}

#underDiv {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <p>OUR SERVICE PROMISE</p>
</div>

<div id="underDiv"><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `p` tag from the circle, and then add another div that wraps both of them. Trigger the animation based on the hover state of that wrapper

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px 20px 0 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle>img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: #54314E solid 4px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle-wrap:hover .circle:before,
.circle-wrap:focus .circle:before,
.circle-wrap:active .circle:before,
.circle-wrap.active .circle:before {
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -15px;
}

#underDiv {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-wrap">
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <p>OUR SERVICE PROMISE</p>
</div>
<div id="underDiv"><div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It is correct, however I have accepted @Micheal Coker's  answer as he provided a working snippet in the question comments before you posted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be better setup for handling this effect but here's a solution given the current setup.

On `:hover` of the circle add some extra `margin-bottom` to account for the extra amount the border circle grows. For example, your circle grows by 15px in radius, so increase the `margin-bottom` on the `.circle` by `15px`. Then add a `transition` to the `margin-bottom` on the `.circle` to transition add the same speed as the circle border grows.

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: margin-bottom;
  transition-property: margin-bottom;
}

.circle > p {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle>img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: #54314E solid 4px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle:hover {
  margin-bottom: 55px;
}

.circle:hover:before,
.circle:focus:before,
.circle:active:before,
.circle.active:before {
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -15px;
}

#underDiv {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <p>OUR SERVICE PROMISE</p>
</div>

<div id="underDiv"><div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you've taken in answering this. I am sorry but I may not have been precise enough in my original question. I was looking to fix the spacing irrespective of the animation/transition. All I wanted was the red block to space consistantly like in @Michael Coker's answer. Thanks again for the answer, I will try and be more precise next time.